# How can you allow executables from a trusted publisher to avoid UAC prompt?

Tags: certificate, uac, windows-server-2016

Full disclosure - I am not a skilled developer.

However, I have built and properly signed a small application for a client in C# - signing it with a proper code-signing certificate from Sectigo, in hope that I could avoid being blocked by UAC.

The application runs in an RDS environment, and so users cannot bypass the UAC prompt, themselves.

I have searched what feels like a million places, but I have clearly still to find a working solution.

An ELI5 ([*Explain Like I'm 5yr-old*](https://www.howtogeek.com/694298/what-does-eli5-mean-and-how-do-you-use-it/)) would be great..

[image: UAC prompt]
[image: Certificate information]

Comment: I'd think you would need to design the app installer to be per-user install (or a portable self-contained executable), otherwise I assume it'd need UAC administrator to install for all-users (per-machine) install: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/allusers

Comment: '[ClickOnce deployment enables non-administrative users to install](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2022)'. So Microsoft DOES support a installation method that is a per-user install getting around the admin/UAC prompt. [ClickOne sign app/manifect guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests?view=vs-2022). This honestly is likely to be answered better on stackoverflow or serverfault (RDS is usually a business technology)

Comment: Is the certificate signed by a Root CA that is an acceptable code signing certificate per Microsoft's requirements?  I am not familiar with Sectigo as a Root CA.  Worth pointing out that the UAC prompt, is typically only required, when the application permissions are elevated.   The dialog that is avoided by using a properly signed code signing certificate, isn't typically considered to be the UAC, but instead a Windows Defender dialog associated with the reputation of the file itself.